# Javascript .apply with IIFE not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to learn javascript .call

```
    var person = {
    firstname: 'John',
    lasname: 'Doe',
    getFullName: function(){
        var fullname = this.firstname + ' ' + this.lasname;
        return fullname;
    }
}


(function(lang1, lang2) {
    console.log('Logged::' + this.getFullName());
    console.log('Arguments ' + lang1, lang2);
    console.log("----------")
}).call(person,'dasdf','asdf');
```

I am getting the error

> Uncaught TypeError: {(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)} is not a function

What is wrong with my code. I am learning from some tutorial.

Comment: missing `;` before `(function` - this is why many examples of IIFE start with `;(function` - because the `;` is often times **very** important

Comment: Please make it as an answer, so that I can accept it.

Comment: I'm not going to post an answer that basically says "you missed a `;`" :p

Comment: @JaromandaX it crack me up xD.